# How to turn off chrome browser auto update

Tags: google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-devtools, updates, chromium

Tried solutions mentioned below

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates - but unsuccessful .

**Tried solutions mentioned to delete the "update" folder but unable to find it in the location specified in the image below**

[image]

Comment: advanced thanks for any help on this .

Comment: this is not about programming

Comment: This should be posted on Super User.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to delete anything. Chromium updates or auto updates are handled by Google Omaha client aka Google update client. Open run and then type `services.msc` then disable these two Google update services:

```
Google update service (gupdate)
Google update service (gupdatem)
```

This will permanently disable update and auto updates in Chrome, as Chrome will try to invoke Google update service to check for updates and initiate the installation process too.

Update:

The above process will disable automatic updates but it is still possible to update Chrome from **About Google Chrome** page. Google Chrome invokes Google Omaha client and it will find the path of Google Omaha client from here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Update\Clients\{430FD4D0-B729-4F61-AA34-91526481799D}` If you change the this GUID then Google update client will always fail even if it's explicitly launched from Google Chrome. I would append a text to it rather than editing that GUID so that it would be easy to revert back.

Comment: These above services I am disabling it , again it gets started  automatically , though I am having admin access to my system . Not sure what's the reason .

Comment: @Som I have edited my answer again. This works even if automatic updates are invoked from Chrome too.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted this on a bunch of these chrome auto update issues and reportedly it has worked on both Windows and Linux, so perhaps it might help you as well?

Pass this flag to chrome every time you are running it.

```
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```

You can set a future date. This will let Chrome / Chromium think that it shouldn't be outdated until this date and therefore won't show the outdated message.

By Adalbert Michelic adalbert@lopez.at 
"It's possible to silence this notification by faking the build date
by using this command line parameter:
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'"
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668#15